# Tidymodels - Help evaluating regression models made via recipes

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am working with the current tidytuesday data about salaries and trying to create a model with tidymodels and recipes. I want to predict salary with many of the other factors present using the recipes code, but I run into an issue.

Issue 1 - My recipe says there are empty rows, but I do not know how to figure out how. This does not give an error, so maybe it is not a problem.

Issue 2 - Understanding what my models actually did and how to visualize the performance. I want to plot the models performance on the initial data. Here is an example of my goal: https://indescribled.files.wordpress.com/2021/05/image-17.png?w=782

I do not understand exactly how to use the predict function with my recipe. juice(rec) is less than 1000 rows while the testing data is about 6000. Perhaps I am reading it backwards, but can someone try to point me in the right direction?

The code below should be an exact reproduction of mine.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

salary_raw <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-05-18/survey.csv')

# Could not figure out tidy way to do this
salary_raw$other_monetary_comp[is.na(salary_raw$other_monetary_comp)] <- 0
salary_raw$other_monetary_comp <- as.numeric(salary_raw$other_monetary_comp)

# Filter and convert to USD
# The mutations to industry were because of other errors, they may not be needed

salary_modeling <- salary_raw %>% 
  filter(
    how_old_are_you %in% c("55-64","45-54","35-44","25-34","18-24"),
    currency %in% c("AUD/NZD","CAD","EUR","GBP","USD")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(annual_salary = case_when(
    currency == "USD" ~ annual_salary * 1.00,
    currency == "GBP" ~ annual_salary * 1.42,
    currency == "AUD/NZD" ~ annual_salary * 0.75,
    currency == "CAD" ~ annual_salary * 0.83,
    currency == "EUR" ~ annual_salary * 1.22
  )) %>% 
  mutate(other_monetary_comp = case_when(
    currency == "USD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.00,
    currency == "GBP" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.42,
    currency == "AUD/NZD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 0.75,
    currency == "CAD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 0.83,
    currency == "EUR" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.22
  )) %>% 
  rename(age = how_old_are_you,
         prof_exp = overall_years_of_professional_experience,
         field_exp = years_of_experience_in_field,
         education = highest_level_of_education_completed
  ) %>% 
  mutate(total_comp = annual_salary + other_monetary_comp) %>% 
  filter(total_comp > 10000,
         total_comp < 350000)%>% 
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    gender == "Prefer not to answer" ~ "Other or prefer not to answer",
    TRUE ~ gender
  )) %>% 
  mutate(industry = case_when(
    industry == "Biotech pharmaceuticals" ~ "Biotech",
    industry == "Consumer Packaged Goods" ~ "Consumer packaged goods ",
    industry == "Real Estate Development" ~ "Real Estate",
    TRUE ~ industry
  ))

# Create initial splits

set.seed(123)
salary_split <- initial_split(salary_modeling)
salary_train <- training(salary_split)
salary_test <- testing(salary_split)

# I want to predict total comp with many of the other variables, listed below. Here is my logic
# downsample is because there are a lot more women than men in the data, unsure if necessary
# log is to many data more interpretable, not necessary
# an error message told me to use novel
# unknown is to change NA to unknown as far as I understand
# other is to change values that are less than 5% of the total dataset to "Other"
# unsure what the purpose of dummy is, but it seems to be necessary for modeling

rec <- salary_train %>% 
  recipe(total_comp ~ age + gender + field_exp + race + industry + job_title) %>%
  themis::step_downsample(gender) %>%
  step_log(total_comp, base = 2) %>%
  step_novel(race, industry) %>% 
  step_unknown(race, industry, gender) %>%
  step_other(race, industry, job_title, threshold = .005) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  prep()

# ISSUE 1 - Running rec says that there are 19,081 data points and 226 incomplete rows. I do not know how to fix the incomplete rows

test_proc <- bake(rec, new_data = salary_test)

# Linear model ------------------------------------------------------------

lm_spec <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

lm_fitted <- lm_spec %>% 
  fit(total_comp ~ ., data = juice(rec))
tidy(lm_fitted)

# RF MODEL ----------------------------------------------------------------

rf_spec <- rand_forest(mode = "regression", trees = 1500) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger")

rf_fit <- rf_spec %>% 
  fit(total_comp ~ ., 
      data = juice(rec))  
rf_fit

# QUESTIONS BEGIN HERE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Need to figure out what new data is for this portion
# I think it is juice(rec), but it seems weird to me
# juice(rec) is only about 900 rows while test_proc is multiple thousand. testing data should be smaller than training
asdf <- juice(rec)

results_train <- lm_fitted %>% 
  predict(new_data = asdf) %>% 
  mutate(
    truth = asdf$total_comp,
    model = "lm"
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows(rf_fit %>% 
              predict(new_data = asdf) %>% 
              mutate(
                truth = asdf$total_comp,
                model = "rf"
              ))
results_train

# Is the newdata and test proc correct?
results_test <- lm_fitted %>% 
  predict(new_data = test_proc) %>% 
  mutate(
    truth = test_proc$total_comp,
    model = "lm"
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(rf_fit %>%
              predict(new_data = test_proc) %>%
              mutate(
                truth = test_proc$total_comp,
                model = "rf"
              ))
results_test

# Goal is to run the following code to visualize the predictions, the code below probably will do nothing right now unless the two dataframes above are correct

results_test %>% 
  mutate(train = "testing") %>% 
  bind_rows(results_train %>% 
              mutate(train = "training")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(truth, .pred, color = model)) +
    geom_abline(lty = 2, color = "gray80", size = 1.5) +
    geom_point(alpha = .75) +
    facet_wrap(~train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have things pretty well along!

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

salary_raw <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-05-18/survey.csv')
#> 
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> cols(
#>   timestamp = col_character(),
#>   how_old_are_you = col_character(),
#>   industry = col_character(),
#>   job_title = col_character(),
#>   additional_context_on_job_title = col_character(),
#>   annual_salary = col_double(),
#>   other_monetary_comp = col_character(),
#>   currency = col_character(),
#>   currency_other = col_character(),
#>   additional_context_on_income = col_character(),
#>   country = col_character(),
#>   state = col_character(),
#>   city = col_character(),
#>   overall_years_of_professional_experience = col_character(),
#>   years_of_experience_in_field = col_character(),
#>   highest_level_of_education_completed = col_character(),
#>   gender = col_character(),
#>   race = col_character()
#> )

salary_modeling <- salary_raw %>% 
  replace_na(list(other_monetary_comp = 0)) %>%
  filter(
    how_old_are_you %in% c("55-64","45-54","35-44","25-34","18-24"),
    currency %in% c("AUD/NZD","CAD","EUR","GBP","USD")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(annual_salary = case_when(
    currency == "USD" ~ annual_salary * 1.00,
    currency == "GBP" ~ annual_salary * 1.42,
    currency == "AUD/NZD" ~ annual_salary * 0.75,
    currency == "CAD" ~ annual_salary * 0.83,
    currency == "EUR" ~ annual_salary * 1.22
  )) %>% 
  mutate(other_monetary_comp = parse_number(other_monetary_comp),
         other_monetary_comp = case_when(
    currency == "USD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.00,
    currency == "GBP" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.42,
    currency == "AUD/NZD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 0.75,
    currency == "CAD" ~ other_monetary_comp * 0.83,
    currency == "EUR" ~ other_monetary_comp * 1.22
  )) %>% 
  rename(age = how_old_are_you,
         prof_exp = overall_years_of_professional_experience,
         field_exp = years_of_experience_in_field,
         education = highest_level_of_education_completed
  ) %>% 
  mutate(total_comp = annual_salary + other_monetary_comp) %>% 
  filter(total_comp > 10000,
         total_comp < 350000) %>% 
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    gender == "Prefer not to answer" ~ "Other or prefer not to answer",
    TRUE ~ gender
  )) %>% 
  mutate(industry = case_when(
    industry == "Biotech pharmaceuticals" ~ "Biotech",
    industry == "Consumer Packaged Goods" ~ "Consumer packaged goods ",
    industry == "Real Estate Development" ~ "Real Estate",
    TRUE ~ industry
  ))

set.seed(123)
salary_split <- initial_split(salary_modeling)
salary_train <- training(salary_split)
salary_test <- testing(salary_split)

rec <- salary_train %>% 
  recipe(total_comp ~ age + gender + field_exp + race + industry + job_title) %>%
  themis::step_downsample(gender) %>%
  step_log(total_comp, base = 2) %>%
  step_novel(race, industry) %>% 
  step_unknown(race, industry, gender) %>%
  step_other(race, industry, job_title, threshold = 0.005) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())
```

The recipe here says the training data has incomplete rows because there is missing data; this is why you used `step_unknown()`, I am guessing.

```r
prep(rec)
#> Data Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor          6
#> 
#> Training data contained 19080 data points and 235 incomplete rows. 
#> 
#> Operations:
#> 
#> Down-sampling based on gender [trained]
#> Log transformation on total_comp [trained]
#> Novel factor level assignment for race, industry [trained]
#> Unknown factor level assignment for race, industry, gender [trained]
#> Collapsing factor levels for race, industry, job_title [trained]
#> Dummy variables from age, gender, field_exp, race, industry, job_title [trained]
```

The processed training set here does not have so many observations any more because of the downsampling; we don't apply downsampling to a test set because we want to compute metrics on test set as they would appear "in the wild".

```r
train_proc <- rec %>% prep() %>% bake(new_data = NULL)
test_proc  <- rec %>% prep() %>% bake(new_data = salary_test)
dim(train_proc)
#> [1] 878  57
dim(test_proc)
#> [1] 6361   57


lm_fitted <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  fit(total_comp ~ ., data = train_proc)

rf_fitted <- rand_forest(mode = "regression", trees = 1500) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>%
  fit(total_comp ~ ., data = train_proc)
```

I'd try using the `augment()` function to make your visualization

```r
bind_rows(
  augment(lm_fitted, new_data = train_proc) %>% mutate(model = "lm", train = "train"),
  augment(rf_fitted, new_data = train_proc) %>% mutate(model = "rf", train = "train"),
  augment(lm_fitted, new_data = test_proc) %>% mutate(model = "lm", train = "test"),
  augment(rf_fitted, new_data = test_proc) %>% mutate(model = "rf", train = "test")
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(total_comp, .pred, color = model)) +
  geom_abline(lty = 2, color = "gray80", size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  facet_wrap(~ train)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>